# Plug into a mobile OS core app

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8

I was wondering if it is possible to develop a sort of plugin for core mobile apps. For example if i would want to add some functionality to the mail app (of iOS/Android/WP8) without having to rewrite a whole mail app with that extra functionality.

To illustrate: lets say i wanted to add functionality to the text message app. The moment when someone gets a text-message I would want to look up this number in an external database (with 3G or Wifi) and get that person's facebook ID and have the possibility of replying to his facebook account instead of his phone.

Would this be something that can be done on iOS, android and WP8 without having to write my own texting app, but instead just plugin in to the core apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible on any of those platforms.

It would be a too big security breach if a third-party app could run inside of any other app.